# YAML-standard parameter specification not one of the allowed types

Tags: ros2, yaml, parameters, rclpy

I'm having a problem regarding code migration from ROS Noetic to ROS Foxy.
The problem is related to parameter access from scripts. I'm using Python nodes for my code.
Originally these sorts of YAML parameters were acceptable for `rospy`:

---

YAML file section:

```yaml
    tf_static: [
      {"frame_id": "map",
      "child_frame_id": "odom",
      "translation": [0.0,0.0,0.0],
      "rotation": [0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
      },
      {"frame_id": "base_link",
      "child_frame_id": "cam_link",
      "translation": [0.06,0.0,0.08],
      "rotation": [-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5]
      },
    ]
    a: {
        b: 1,
        c: 2.0,
        d: "hello",
        e: true
    }
```

rospy script section (using if-else rather than get_param w/ defaults for better visibility wherever necessary):

```py
    if rospy.has_param('tf_static'):
      tf_static = rospy.get_param('tf_static')
    else: #defaults
      tf_static = [
                        {"frame_id": "map",
                        "child_frame_id": "odom",
                        "translation": [0.0,0.0,0.0],
                        "rotation": [0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
                        },
                        {"frame_id": "base_link",
                        "child_frame_id": "cam_link",
                        "translation": [0.05,0.0,0.08],
                        "rotation": [-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5]
                        },
                      ]
    another_param_dict = rospy.get_param('a', default={'b':1,'c':2.0,'d':"hello",'e':True})
    just_a_field = tf_static[0]['frame_id'] # just an example
    just_another_field = another_param_dict['d'] # just another example to expand
```

---

Considering that `parameter.py` in the [source code](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/9536f8ec66020a552cf9ad421a11629ad8804a16/rclpy/rclpy/parameter.py#L185) does not include this functionality with `get_parameter_value`, and `parameter_dict_from_yaml_file` simply points to a YAML file to go through the same thing recursively, this becomes a great hassle.
Declaration is another problem, considering nothing in this case is allowed in the first place. I *can* (only) get `a` to work, by explicitly specifying `a.b`, `a.c`, `a.d`, and `a.e`, but a list of dictionaries is "non-standard" (not by YAML conventions, of course) so I am completely stuck there.

```py
# self refers to the Node, i.e. `class my_node(Node)`
...
# ridiculously messy, and only works with "standard" types
self.declare_parameter('a.b',"1")
self.declare_parameter('a.c',"2.0")
self.declare_parameter('a.d',"hello")
self.declare_parameter('a.e',"true")
self.b = self.get_parameter('a.b').get_parameter_value().integer_value
self.c = self.get_parameter('a.c').get_parameter_value().double_value
self.d = self.get_parameter('a.d').get_parameter_value().string_value
self.e = self.get_parameter('a.e').get_parameter_value().bool_value
```

Furthermore, the **original** idea of using lists of dictionaries for me was to have as many of these descriptions as I wanted for my static frame definitions so I could simply enter them in my YAML file in this manner. Now I can't even think about using many parameters without typing them in one by one in my rclpy node initialization.

Is this seriously what we are stuck with for moving on with ROS 2, or is there a way to properly get parameters from YAML files? I seriously am considering hacking into the parameter file using `ament` packages, or some relative address definitions, and `yaml` to just parse the parameter file myself and eliminate the problem. I am not even interested in modifying these parameters at runtime either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use the wrong tool for what you're looking to do. ROS parameters are designed to provide runtime adjustable parameters for nodes that are introspectable and can be interacted with remotely. In the ROS 2 design their functionality was extended to be able to be more dynamic and support parameter charge events we tc. But to provide those capabilities what is allowed as a parameter is more restricted. For example mixed types that you're looking to use. Parameters are not designed to carry arbitrary unstructured data.

From your description it sounds like what you're looking for is more of a configuration file that can be read in at startup of the node. You can do this with your choice of configuration system, such as loading a yaml file. This configuration file can follow whatever semantics that you'd like.

Comment: Yeah, doing so via ament's package share finder and yaml does the trick.   I do actually have the solution, but I just hoped to have a very ROS way of doing it. I'll mark this as the answer for now for at least, and drop an easy way of reliably doing whatever I intend to do later.

Comment: The core of ROS is the middleware and transport. We try not to reinvent the wheel for things that have good existing solution. In this case I would expect that it's hard for ROS to implement something better than [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) or a simple command line argument plus an invocation of `yaml.safe_load(arg)` which are both core packages in python.

Answer (score 0):

I'll follow up with a solution to this problem for anyone else who needs to implement a similar node.
First, make sure you add your loadable configuration, `load_params.y[a]ml` to your `config` folder, as such:

```
colcon_ws
└── src
    ├── my_pkg
    │   ├── config
    │   │   └── load_params.yml
    │   ├── my_pkg
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── my_node.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │       └── my_node.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── launch
    │   │   ├── backend_launcher.launch.py
    │   │   └── frontend_launcher.launch.xml
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   ├── resource
    │   │   └── my_pkg
    │   ├── setup.cfg
    │   ├── setup.py
    │   └── test
    │       ├── test_copyright.py
    │       ├── test_flake8.py
    │       └── test_pep257.py
```

In your `setup.py`, modify it accordingly to have a copy of `config` in your `install` share space (doesn't hurt to add your launchers too):

```py
import os
from glob import glob
...
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        # Include all configuration files
        ('share/' + package_name + '/config', glob('config/*')),
        # Include all launch files
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob(os.path.join('launch', '*launch.[pxy][yma]*')))
    ],
    ...
)
```

Once you've done this, you can invoke, in *any* Python file that you have placed in `install` (be it a node or launch.py) the following:

```py
import yaml
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
...
share_dir = get_package_share_directory(PKG_NAME) # modify this accordingly
fname = share_dir + f"/config/load_params.yaml" # use os.path.join if you want
with open(fname, 'r') as file:
  configs = yaml.safe_load(file)
# # note that you will most likely extract a field as the following
# # or, using ['<ns>/<node>'] instead of ['/**'] 
# # you can also simply discard the typical ros2 param syntax 
# # # if you won't use any of the fields in a parameter declaration
# config_field = configs['/**']['ros__parameters']['field_name']
```

Using this in launch backends helps with conditional statements tied in with launch file generation that are **not** intrinsic properties of the sub-launch files themselves (e.g. how many launch files are you spawning).
In nodes, this allows your nodes to access *configurations* rather than *node parameters*, according to the distinction made in [the previously given answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/107852/31285)
Hope this helps anyone else who is stumped!